# Lint error "Do not treat position as fixed; only use immediately..."

Tags: android, lint, android-recyclerview

I'm contributing to open source library and got lint error **"Do not treat position as fixed; only use immediately and call holder.getAdapterPosition() to look it up later"** for this code:

```
  @Override public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    mAdapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);

    if (!isFirstOnly || position > mLastPosition) {
      for (Animator anim : getAnimators(holder.itemView)) {
        anim.setDuration(mDuration).start();
        anim.setInterpolator(mInterpolator);
      }
      mLastPosition = position;
    } else {
      ViewHelper.clear(holder.itemView);
    }
  }
```

I've checked that it is because the position is saved for the future use. It is a question to library creator why they need this logic. But issue disappeared when I change the usage of the position to the usage `holder.getAdapterPosition()`:

```
  @Override public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    mAdapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);

    if (!isFirstOnly || holder.getAdapterPosition() > mLastPosition) {
      for (Animator anim : getAnimators(holder.itemView)) {
        anim.setDuration(mDuration).start();
        anim.setInterpolator(mInterpolator);
      }
      mLastPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
    } else {
      ViewHelper.clear(holder.itemView);
    }
  }
```

I assume that conceptually it didn't change much but lint is satisfied now. Why?

Comment: There is no guarantee that the bind will be called in perfect order in which item views are actually visible. So, `mLastPosition` might not be the last item visible.

Comment: Ok, this is good input to library creators, but why lint is satisfied now?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Update:**
The method `getAdapterPosition()` is [deprecated now](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAdapterPosition()).

---

The documentation of [RecyclerView.Adapter.onBindViewHolder()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder%28VH,%20int,%20java.util.List%3Cjava.lang.Object%3E%29) states:

> Note that unlike ListView, RecyclerView will not call this method
> again if the position of the item changes in the data set unless the
> item itself is invalidated or the new position cannot be determined.
> For this reason, you should only use the position parameter while
> acquiring the related data item inside this method and should not keep
> a copy of it. If you need the position of an item later on (e.g. in a
> click listener), use getAdapterPosition() which will have the updated
> adapter position

So, technically items may be re-arranged (like sorted, or moved around) and binding will not be necessary because items are not invalidated yet. This means   `onBindViewHolder()` may NOT be called if items show the same data, but just their position/index in a list changes. The `position` variable received holds true only for the scope of bind function and will not always point to the correct position in the data set. That's why the function `getAdapterPosition()` must be called every time updated position is needed.

IMHO, `mLastPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();` is still potentially wrong. Because item may be re-arranged and `mLastPosition` still points to old position.

About why lint is silent, perhaps Lint's rule is not that thorough. It's only checking whether the `position` parameter is being copied or not.

Comment: Actually it is failing on linux build, but passes on mac

Comment: Then why is Google putting out samples with code that will cause this lint error?

Comment: Weird. I guess they're planning something.

Comment: @S.D. Could you elaborate on _"mLastPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition(); is still potentially wrong."_? Why is it potentially wrong?

Comment: @JuusoOhtonen Because item may be re-arranged and `mLastPosition` still points to old position when used elsewhere.

Comment: @taurelas The lint tool analyses the code files based on rules. Rules are programs that can access source constructs and look for bad patterns. [Here is an example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-custom-lint-rules/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/google/lint/MainActivityDetector.java)

Comment: @S.D. ok, so it's a custom rule to accompany the library. Thanks.

Comment: 'getAdapterPosition()' is deprecated use getBindingAdapterPosition instead

Answer (score 3):

My old code:

```
@Override

//here int position gave a error

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartListAdapator.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.titleTxt.setText(foodDomains.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.feeEachItem.setText(String.valueOf(foodDomains.get(position).getFee()));

    
    holder.plusItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            managementCart.plusNumberFood(foodDomains, position, new ChangeNumberItemListener() {
                @Override
                public void changed() {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    changeNumberItemListener.changed();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

So, in plusNumberFood() method I changed the parameter position -> holder.getAdapterPosition();

My new code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartListAdapator.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.titleTxt.setText(foodDomains.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.feeEachItem.setText(String.valueOf(foodDomains.get(position).getFee()));

    holder.plusItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            managementCart.plusNumberFood(foodDomains, holder.getAdapterPosition(), new ChangeNumberItemListener() {
                @Override
                public void changed() {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    changeNumberItemListener.changed();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```