# Get spinner selected item inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-spinner

I have added `Spinner` inside `RecyclerView` , when i am trying to get spinner selected item data, its getting another/wrong position data, any one suggest me to get correct selected item and position from `Spinner` `onItemSelected`

Here is my code

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final QuestionHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (position % 2 == 1)
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F8F8F8"));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Option>(binding.getRoot().getContext(),
                        R.layout.item_spinner, questionList.get(position).getOptions());
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.item_spinner);
        binding.optionSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        binding.serialNo.setText((position + 1) + ".");
        binding.setQuestion(questionList.get(position));
        binding.executePendingBindings();
        binding.optionSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), position+" : "+binding.optionSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                spinnerData.setSelectedData(position, binding.optionSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: call `setOnItemSelectedListener` inside your custom `QuestionHolder`, not inside `onBindViewHolder` method, also do not create `ArrayAdapter` there - do that in `QuestionHolder` too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to try this

```
  showSpinnerList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new 
         AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
               position, long id) {
                // On selecting a spinner item

                String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // todo for nothing selected
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this, can be helpful and may fix your problem. If this won't fix your problem at least you get rid of Lint error. [Lint error “Do not treat position as fixed; only use immediately…”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34943270/4858147). So everywhere you are using `final int position**` change it to `getAdapterPosition()`;

> The documentation of [RecyclerView.Adapter.onBindViewHolder()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int,%20java.util.List%3Cjava.lang.Object%3E))
> states:
>
> > Note that unlike ListView, RecyclerView will not call this method
> > again if the position of the item changes in the data set unless the
> > item itself is invalidated or the new position cannot be determined.
> > For this reason, you should only use the position parameter while
> > acquiring the related data item inside this method and should not keep
> > a copy of it. If you need the position of an item later on (e.g. in a
> > click listener), use getAdapterPosition() which will have the updated
> > adapter position
>
> > So, technically items may be re-arranged and binding will not be
> > necessary because items are not invalidated yet. The `position`
> > variable received holds true only for the scope of bind function and
> > will not always point to correct position in the data set. That's why
> > the function `getAdapterPosition()` must be called everytime updated
> > position is needed.
> >
> > IMHO, `mLastPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();` is still
> > potentially wrong. Because item may be re-arranged and `mLastPosition`
> > still points to old position.
> >
> > About why lint is silent, perhaps Lint rule is not that thorough. Its
> > only checking whether `position` parameter is being copied or not.