# how to fix Do not treat position as fixed; only use immediately and call holder.getAdapterPosition() android?

Tags: android, adapter

I even used `final int position` in the position place,Do not treat position as fixed; only use immediately and call holder.getAdapterPosition() to look it up later error show

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (holder instanceof OriginalViewHolder) {
            final Recipe p = items.get(position);
            final OriginalViewHolder vItem = (OriginalViewHolder) holder;

            vItem.category_name.setText(p.category_name);
            vItem.recipe_title.setText(p.recipe_title);

            vItem.price.setPaintFlags(vItem.price.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

            vItem.price.setText("₹" +p.price);

            vItem.discountprice.setText("₹" +p.discountprice);

            double price = Double.parseDouble(p.price);
            double discountprice = Double.parseDouble(p.discountprice);

            int discountPercentage = (int) (( (int) (((discountprice / price) - 1) * 100)));


            vItem.discountpricetext.setText( Integer.toString(discountPercentage)+ "%OFF");



            ((OriginalViewHolder) holder).btnaddqty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Log.d("src", "Decreasing value...");
                    _counter--;
                    _stringVal = Integer.toString(_counter);
                    vItem.value.setText(_stringVal);



                    if (_counter < 0)
                    {
                        vItem.value.setText("0");
                    }



                    databaseHandler = new DbHandler(context);

                    databaseHandler.Addcart(items.get(position).getId(), vItem.value);


                }
            });







            if (p.content_type != null && p.content_type.equals("youtube")) {
                Picasso.get()
                        .load(Constant.YOUTUBE_IMAGE_FRONT + p.video_id + Constant.YOUTUBE_IMAGE_BACK_MQ)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail)
                        .into(vItem.recipe_image);
            } else {
                Picasso.get()
                        .load(sharedPref.getApiUrl() + "/upload/" + p.recipe_image)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail)
                        .into(vItem.recipe_image);
            }

            if (p.content_type != null && p.content_type.equals("Post")) {
                vItem.thumbnail_video.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                vItem.thumbnail_video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            vItem.lyt_parent.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                    mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, p, position);
                }
            });

        } else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }

        if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_PROG) {
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
        } else {
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.setFullSpan(false);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lint error "Do not treat position as fixed; only use immediately..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942840/lint-error-do-not-treat-position-as-fixed-only-use-immediately)